# How to find checkbox under specific heading using bs4?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the checked boxes (or really all information), for certain questions on the following [url](https://reporting.unpri.org/surveys/PRI-Reporting-Framework-2016/680d94eb-3777-49f7-a1c0-3f0ac42b8b5e/79894dbc337a40828d895f9402aa63de/html/2/?lang=&a=1).

Example i want to find the information under the heading *"01.1. Select the category which best represents your primary activity."* and if i does not exist i want a blank space.

This is my current code:

```
from splinter import *
import bs4 as bs
import os
import time
import csv
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementNotVisibleException

path = os.getcwd()+'/chromedriver.exe'
executable_path = {'executable_path': path}
browser = Browser('chrome', **executable_path)

urls = ['https://www.unpri.org/organisation/folksam-143819']

for i in urls:
    browser.visit(i)
    window = browser.windows[0]
    window.is_current = True
    temp_list = []
    sourcenew = browser.html
    soupnew = bs.BeautifulSoup(sourcenew, 'lxml')
    temp_list.append(browser.url)


    for info in soupnew.find_all('span', class_ = 'org-type' ):
        string_com = str(info.text)
        if len(string_com) == 16:
            string_com = string_com.replace(' ', ' ')[1:-1]
        elif len(string_com) == 11:
            string_com = string_com.replace(' ', ' ')[1:-1]
        elif len(string_com) == 10:
            string_com = string_com.replace(' ', ' ')[1:-1]
        elif len(string_com) == 12:
            string_com = string_com.replace(' ', ' ')[1:-1]
        elif len(string_com) == 13:
            string_com = string_com.replace(' ', ' ')[1:-1]
        else:
            string_com = string_com.replace(' ', ' ')[40:-37]
        temp_list.append(string_com)
    if len(browser.find_by_xpath('//*[@id="main-
content"]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/p/a')) > 0:
        browser.find_by_xpath('//*[@id="main-
content"]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/p/a').click()
        time.sleep(2)
        if len(browser.windows) > 1:
            window = browser.windows[1]
            window.is_current = True

            sourcenew2 = browser.html
            soupnew2 = bs.BeautifulSoup(sourcenew2, 'lxml')



    oo = soupnew2.find_all('h3', class_ = 'n-h3')
        for o in oo:
            print(o)
            if """Select the category which best represents your primary activity.""" in o:
                t = o.find('img', class_='readradio')
                if t and '/Style/img/checkedradio.png' in t.get('src'):
                    content = o.find('span', class_='title')
                    temp_list.append(content.text.strip())
                    print(temp_list)
```

This however does not give an output. I would like the output to be like:

```
    ["Insurance company"]
```

If the question is answered, and

```
    [" "]
```

If not

Comment: can you post the preceding code where that page is requested?

Comment: Yes sorry, i'll update it now

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with this pattern:

1) Iterate every `tag` with the `indent type_^ parent_S` class to get the sub-questions;

2) iterate every `h3` (The sub question) for:
   - A fake radio button (img) with `/Style/img/checkedradio.png` as the source;
   - A real radio button with the `checked` attribute;

3) If it founds one of those, create a key-value pair and insert in a previous created `dict`;

4) If not, create a key-value pair with an empty value and insert it ina  previous created `dict`.

5) Analyse the data;

Here is a code snippet so you can work it further:

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("https://reporting.unpri.org/surveys/PRI-Reporting-Framework-2016/680d94eb-3777-49f7-a1c0-3f0ac42b8b5e/79894dbc337a40828d895f9402aa63de/html/2/?lang=&a=1").text, "html.parser")

parent = soup.select('div[class="indent type_^ parent_S"]')
header_values = {}

for r in parent:
    headers = r.find_all("h3")
    for header in headers:
        if header is not None:
            fake_radio_button = r.find("img", src="/Style/img/checkedradio.png")
            real_radio_button = r.select("input[checked='checked']")

            if fake_radio_button == None:
                if real_radio_button == None:
                    header_values[re.sub(r'[\t\r\n]', '', header.get_text(strip=True).strip())] = ""
                else:
                    if len(real_radio_button) > 0:
                        header_values[re.sub(r'[\t\r\n]', '', header.get_text(strip=True).strip())] = real_radio_button[0].attrs["data-original"]
                    else:
                        header_values[re.sub(r'[\t\r\n]', '', header.get_text(strip=True).strip())] = ""
            else:
                header_values[re.sub(r'[\t\r\n]', '', header.get_text(strip=True).strip())] = fake_radio_button.parent.find("span").get_text(strip=True)
```

Which will output:

> `{'01.1.            Select the category which best represents your primary activity.': 'Insurance company', '01.2.            Additional information. [Optional]': 'Insurance company',....}`

Comment: Is there a way to do this with the output being a list? Also im not interested in the header, but only the answers (checkedboxes and text) under certain headers that i specify.